# Is it possible to apply Proguard to just part of an Android codebase?

Tags: android, proguard

So I've arrived on a work project that isn't in the best of states. There's several problems with the code but one issue I have is that Proguard isn't running on it, meaning we're missing several optimisations.

I don't have the time/capacity to test the app all the way through (which I'd have to do if I were to apply Proguard to the entire codebase) and also get features done so I'd like to introduce Proguard as I work, meaning being selective with where it is applied.

Does this sound doable? Are there any recommendations for an approach? 
The Proguard manual is a good reference for what each option does but I've never really felt like its a "guide" per se.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add keep classes attribute for the classes which you don't want to add to proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Good way I can think of is, take up a generic Proguard file and run through few iterations with 'minifyEnabled' true and for the errors you get, apply

`--keep class com.example.** { *; }` (for that entire package)

`--keep class com.example.MainClass { *; }` (for that entire class)

Do it till you are able to build successfully and install apk successfully.
That should be quick(comparing to doing the same without --keep) as you expected.

Best way to do is, take time, do it right.
Trust me, the above shortcut and doing it straight don't really show much time difference, cause you need to understand proguard basics for both cases.

A quick guide which discusses easing the process is [here](https://medium.com/@neeluiscoming/how-simple-setting-up-proguard-is-and-how-we-make-it-hard-35edb33653a4). Hope it helps.